# TextView value changed in last N seconds

Tags: android, textview

How to check in Android if the value in TextView has not changed in last 2 seconds.

I have a condition that value in a TextView is kept changing as my app receiving data from Bluetooth.

I have to check when data stops coming, so on basis of that, I can update my UI.

Here is my code for handling text view

```
 textOngoingBP.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
       Logger.log(Level.DEBUG,TAG, --OnText CHanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
       // startTest and stopTest is button for start test                                                
       startTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       stopTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       Logger.log(Level.DEBUG,TAG,"--AfterText Changed");
    }
});
```

Here I have to make start button visible and stop button gone when no data is coming. Any idea?

Comment: Could you update your question and tag to say if you are using Java or Kotlin please.

Comment: @AnthonyCannon , it's in java

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer and reset the timer every time that a TextView has been edited.

Try this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

//timer.schedule(new MyTask(),2000);

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("TAG","2 seconds.");            
        }
    }


textOngoingBP.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
         //timer.cancel();
         //timer = new Timer();
         //timer.schedule(new MyTask(),2000);  
         Logger.log(Level.DEBUG,TAG, --OnText CHanged");                                     
    }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

         timer.schedule(new MyTask(),2000);                                             
    startTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    stopTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                                               
    Logger.log(Level.DEBUG,TAG,"--AfterText CHanged");
           }
          }
        );
```

Comment: @ Augusto .I am getting an error while canceling timer.W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled

Comment: Try reinstance the timer: `timer = new Timer();` I've edited answer.

Comment: here the problem is MyTask does get executed after 2 sec, which I don't want, what I want it is only executed after data is stopped coming

Comment: Somehow it is not able to cancel completely the timer

Comment: You want that the timer execute, for 2 seconds, after all data coming?

Comment: see my code - in OnTextChanged()--try{
                                                        myTimer.cancel();
                                                        myTimer=new Timer();
                                                        myTimerTask=new MyTimerTask();
                                                        myTimer.schedule(myTimerTask,500,2000);
                                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                                    }

Comment: Yes Exactly what I want, to execute the timer after the value stop coming in textview

Comment: I've edited, I don't know why editor put red text color. So, I think you need arm timer in the `afterTextChanged`, maybe have a function `endTextChanged`. So, the time is fired after text comming.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this, that saves the time it was up last updated.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
 * This class was created by Anthony M Cannon on 15/05/2018.
 */
public class ChangingTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    private long lastUpdated = -1;

    public ChangingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ChangingTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ChangingTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
        super.setText(text, type);
    }

    public long getLastUpdated() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }
}
```

Then you could have a background thread that checks it every so often.